# Scrolling a UIImage using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to allow my image to be `pan` and `zoomable`, however I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my commented code > Create `UIScrollView` > create `PFImageView` (`UIImage`) > add image to `UIScrollView` > Fetch & Display image.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"%@",_courseObject);                         //checking object has loaded

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;                //scroll view occupies full parent view!
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 800);      //scroll view size
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;      //to hide scroll indicators!
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;    //by default, it shows!
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;                     //say "NO" to disable scroll
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];                  //adding to parent view!



    PFImageView *mapImage = [[PFImageView alloc] init];         //create imageview
    mapImage.frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;      //set image boundaries to fill nav frame(!)
    mapImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading"];           //placeholder image
    mapImage.file = (PFFile *)[_courseObject objectForKey:@"file"]; //retrieve the map image

    [scrollView addSubview:mapImage];                               //add the mapImage to scrollView
    [mapImage loadInBackground];                                    //retrieve image and add

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that scrollView.contentSize was not large enough so when attempting to scroll it wasn't picking up the movements.

Changing the values to fill the frame as well as implementing the delegate protocol allowed me to use the scroll view.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a scroll view delegate, to be more specific, you will need to implement this method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

(PFImageView *mapImage has to become an attribute and not a local variable)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSLog(@"%@",_courseObject);                         //checking object has loaded

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;                //scroll view occupies full parent view!
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 800);      //scroll view size
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;      //to hide scroll indicators!
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;    //by default, it shows!
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;                     //say "NO" to disable scroll
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];                  //adding to parent view!
// HERE
scrollView.delegate = self;
// HERE

mapImage = [[PFImageView alloc] init];         //create imageview
mapImage.frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;      //set image boundaries to fill nav frame(!)
mapImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading"];           //placeholder image
mapImage.file = (PFFile *)[_courseObject objectForKey:@"file"]; //retrieve the map image

[scrollView addSubview:mapImage];                               //add the mapImage to scrollView
[mapImage loadInBackground];                                    //retrieve image and add

}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return mapImage;
}
```